# SQL statement selecting most recent date no longer working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've had a sudden failure in one of my reporting routines and have traced it back to the having portion of my statement. The function this has been serving, up until 2 days ago, was selecting the most recent date from the `dbo.data_feed_file` table (column name: `File_Date`).

Statement follows

```
HAVING (dbo.data_feed_file.file_date = (Select MAX(File_Date) as Expr1
                                        FROM dbo.data_feed_file AS data_feed_file_1))
```

First: is there an alternative way to write this? I've gotten my report working by removing the statement, it's just 2.5 million more lines than I want. I know I can hard code the date to pull just the specific date I want, but automation is obviously preferred.

Second: Does anyone know what could cause this to spontaneously fail? I'm the only person with access to edit this query so I know nothing was changed (no really, nothing changed).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To add clarification: There is no error message, the column headers are showing up as anticipated but no data is populated, it's just blank fields (as though nothing met the having criteria). The statement completes as though there is nothing wrong. I've confirmed there are no NULL values in the File_Date column.

Comment: pls post the whole statement, or at least an error message.

Comment: Is there a NULL file_date?  Some RDBMSes sort them as MAX, some as MIN, don't know about Sql Server.

Comment: How is the expression failing?

Comment: Try `SELECT TOP 1 <query> GROUP BY dbo.data_feed_file.file_date ORDER BY dbo.data_feed_file.file_date DESC` -- does that work?

Comment: Sorry, to add clarification: There is no error message, the column headers are showing up as anticipated but no data is populated, it's just blank fields (as though nothing met the having criteria).

Comment: Have you changed schema of any tables used in this query?

Comment: @Karl, aggregate functions ignore nulls, returning null only when there are no rows to operate on, or the expression being maxed or minned is null for every row in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two reasons why no rows would return.  The first is that the subquery is returning NULL.  This is easily fixed as:

```
HAVING (dbo.data_feed_file.file_date = (Select MAX(File_Date) as Expr1
                                        FROM dbo.data_feed_file AS data_feed_file_1
                                        where file_date is not null))
```

The second is that File_Date is stored as a `datetime`, rather than a `date`.  If so, you might have a `where` clause that filters out the most recent value, and be missing it in the `having` clause.  If you intend dates, but the value is stored as a datetime, then you can try:

```
HAVING (cast(dbo.data_feed_file.file_date as date) =
                                        (Select cast(MAX(File_Date) as date) as Expr1
                                        FROM dbo.data_feed_file AS data_feed_file_1
                                        where file_date is not null))
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you nailed the solution.

Comment: @ChrisWoodend; which one was it?  NULL or Datetime?

Comment: @Karl It was datetime. Apparently someone made a schema change in an external database and didn't inform anyone.